# Using Gaussian Kernel to Define Distance

Tags: functions, gaussian

I want to define a region of ball with radius $R$ such that close to center the value is 1 and at the boundary, the value is 0. The gaussian kernel comes to my mind but I would like to know how can I set the $\sigma^2$ such that it works with given radius?

$$f(x,x')=e^{-\tfrac{||x-x'||^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$ such that at $x'=R$ the function is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function that goes to $0$ at $\Vert x-x^\prime\Vert=R$, you could instead use $\left(1-\tfrac{\Vert x-x^\prime\Vert^2}{R^2}\right)^+$ with $y^+:=\max\{y,\,0\}$. A Gaussian kernel never becomes $0$.

Comment: why do we square then? we might as well have L1 norm, right?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER You could, yes. One reason the $L^2$ option is so natural to think of is that the subtracted term becomes a Pythagorean sum over multiple dimensions' contributions. Also, at small separation a Gaussian kernel is $1-\tfrac{\Vert x-x^\prime\Vert^2}{R^2}+O(\Vert x-x^\prime\Vert^4)$ anyway.